# Unity C# get list of files in folder create public enum from array

Tags: c#, enums

The folder structure for this project is

Biophase->UI->Themes->Theme1->Theme1.cs

Biophase->UI->Themes->Theme2->Theme2.cs

Biophase->UI->Themes->Themex->Themex.cs

Biophase->UI->Themer->Themer.cs

In the inspector I need the contents of Themes folder to populate a public dropdown list in Themer.cs, so that the user can select a theme from the available list of themes. The list potentially changing as themes are installed or uninstalled.

Comment: You can dynamically build the list using `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(string path)` on the themes folder, this will give you a list of each theme folder

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre How do I use the created list as a public variable to be accessed in the inspector view?